# Chromium in Delphi. How to access DOM

Tags: delphi, dom, chromium-embedded, cef4delphi

I am using the [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) project.

My goal is to load a page and interrogate the DOM

I defined a event handler `Chromium1.OnDocumentAvailable` in which I can do

```
procedure TMiniBrowserFrm.Chromium1DocumentAvailable(Sender: TObject; const aDocument: ICefDomDocument);
begin
  aDocument.GetElementById('client').ElementBounds;
end;
```

Though, the OnDocumentAvailable **is never called**, even when I load a page using `Chromium1.LoadURL(URL)`.

How is it possible to gain access to the DOM after a Chromium component has loaded a URL ?

Comment: May sound like a dumb question, but are you sure you assigned this event handler to the event?

Comment: Yes I dit, both tried through DFM and through Code

Comment: Interesting, the version of Chromium I have installed (v3) here doesn't have such an event. Must have been just added in v4.

Comment: I'm using cef_binary_3.2924.1571.gcdcdfa9_windows32

Comment: Looking in the source, that event is triggered by a procedure `DOMVisitorVisit` which doesn't appear to be called from anywhere. Keep in mind, it looks like this entire project is in active development, and commits almost every day. You may want to use CEF3 instead.

Comment: How can I access the Document with CEF3 ?

Comment: That would look like `OnLoadEnd` I presume, but I'm just skimming over the properties. But CEF4, the entire project was created exactly 1 month ago, so I wouldn't expect anything there to work yet.

Comment: Same problem. Only have access to the ICefFrame / ICefBrowser. It then requires either VisitDOM(aVisitor : ICefVisitor) or VisitDomProc(aProc : ICefVisitDomProc). Tried both, visit method never gets called...

Answer (score 3):

Download the latest version of CEF4Delphi. It has all what's necessary to access the DOM.

Take a look at the DOMVisitor_OnDocAvailable function in the uDOMVisitor.pas file (DOMVisitor demo).

The old event that you mentioned no longer exists and the DOMVisitor now uses a custom RenderProcessHandler with a TCefFastDomVisitor.

Run the DOMVisitor and right-click on the web page after it's loaded and then select "Visit DOM".

Answer (score 2):

I have not used CEF4, but one of the demos included with CEF 3 shows how to
work with the Chromium DOM.  Unlike TWebBrowser, unfortunately, it is not
a simple matter of grabbing a COM interface as a way into the DOM parser.  So, the reason your current code doesn't work is that you are not taking the necessary steps for working with the DOM.

The relevant CEF3 example is the one called "Guiclient" and it uses a custom
action to invoke DOM handling:

```
procedure TMainForm.actDomExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  crm.browser.SendProcessMessage(PID_RENDERER,
    TCefProcessMessageRef.New('visitdom'));
end;
```

which as you can see involves sending Chromium's rendering process a message,
and using a custom class to work with it:

```
TCustomRenderProcessHandler = class(TCefRenderProcessHandlerOwn)
protected
  procedure OnWebKitInitialized; override;
  function OnProcessMessageReceived(const browser: ICefBrowser; sourceProcess: TCefProcessId;
    const message: ICefProcessMessage): Boolean; override;
end;
[...]
function TCustomRenderProcessHandler.OnProcessMessageReceived(
  const browser: ICefBrowser; sourceProcess: TCefProcessId;
  const message: ICefProcessMessage): Boolean;
begin
//{$IFDEF DELPHI14_UP}
  if (message.Name = 'visitdom') then
    begin
      browser.MainFrame.VisitDomProc(
        procedure(const doc: ICefDomDocument) begin
          doc.Body.AddEventListenerProc('mouseover', True,
            procedure (const event: ICefDomEvent)
            var
              msg: ICefProcessMessage;
            begin
              msg := TCefProcessMessageRef.New('mouseover');
              msg.ArgumentList.SetString(0, getpath(event.Target));
              browser.SendProcessMessage(PID_BROWSER, msg);
            end)
        end);
        Result := True;
    end
  else
//{$ENDIF}
//    Result := False;
end;

procedure TCustomRenderProcessHandler.OnWebKitInitialized;
begin
{$IFDEF DELPHI14_UP}
  TCefRTTIExtension.Register('app', TTestExtension);
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

So, also unlike TWebBrowser, your DOM-handling code doesn't execute in your main thread, and you need to take that into account in your coding.

Good luck.

Comment: Did this help with your q?